# i can not use live ubuntu in other laptop, can use in my laptop only

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, uefi, live-usb

I am new to Linux and installed Ubuntu on my external m2 sata ssd. I successfully installed Ubuntu on it with uefi system, and it started running on my laptop. But when I attached to other laptops Linux was not found on the os boot manager area. I took some help from chatgpt and installed some drivers too. But still no change. I need community help. thank you

Comment: Where is your bootloader (which is different than the OS) installed? On your laptop? Or on the SSD?

Comment: ChatGPT sucks at technical advice. Don't use it for this purpose. The copy of Ubuntu you installed was configured for your architecture and hardware configuration. It won't work with other laptops of different architecture and hardware config. Look for a "Live USB with Persistence". "Persistence" adds a writable partition to the Live USB.